# Adding a CMS (wordpress) to a website?

Tags: css, wordpress, static, content-management-system

I have made a site using html, css and javascript and is only on my local machine and have not put it onto a server yet, but i was wondering if i could use a cms on this site like wordpress? The site is only 5 pages but i have done all the styling myself.

Would i just have to install wordpress to the server and add the files there maybe? Or is there a lot of changes needed to make this work? 
I have very little knowledge of PHP but i am a quick learner if that counts for anything.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: yes

More complicated answer: why?

If your site is only 5 pages, and you've custom designed and built your layout, then I'm not sure what WordPress will add for you.

That said, if you want to add a blog or the like, WP would certainly be nice to have.

If you want to go that route, you have a few options:

- use WordPress for everything, using the 5 pages you made as 'pages' inside of WordPress. You'll have to modify what you built for that to some extent.
- leave the 5 pages as-is but add WordPress 'next to it' and run the blog/cms content from there. It can look the same, or maybe you want it to look a bit different.
- leave your 5-page site as-is, and use WordPress or another CMS product on a separate server. You can set it up as a subdomain and then either install your own, or leverage something like Posterous or Wordpress.com

Comment: + 1 For actually pointing out that adding a CMS might not actually yield any benefits in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is:
it will take some effort, you won't be able to just drop the files and install wordpress and have everything work immediately. With some work, though, it is definitely possible.

If you've done the styling and you want to incorporate that into wordpress you'll have to go through the process of creating your own theme. http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/ Try this site to see what that requires. Alternatively, google "creating your own wordpress theme" or something similar.

It will require some extensive PHP work, but a lot of these tutorials have already done that heavy lifting for you. In any case, it will be worth it for your to pick up some PHP skills, enough to follow along the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this myself and what you can do is integrate your design into an existing design. You could just create your own theme, which takes some time but it is the correct way to do it.

http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

I knew 0 php and I was able to create my own theme in a few hours. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean "add the files there", I assume you means that use a WordPress-based website to display your site, then you can simple create a page by WordPress and then link this page to your site.

But if you means to create a wordpress theme which based on your existing site, then you can search a tutorial and follow it to create a wordpress theme by yourself. Making a wordpress theme will needs some PHP work, but not complicate, wordpress has very detailed documations and API.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Umbraco CMS for it.  The advantage is that you start with an empty site, add your css, js, and create your own content types, paste in your HTML for the templates, and you're ready to go.  It is a perfect CMS for few page sites to larger sites and also has a great community around it, including lots of documentation and screencasts.  Templating is done with the Razor syntax, very easy to learn and lots of documentation.  You'll need to have a Microsoft-based server to host it and this may be a barrier depending on your hosting scenario.